# How to get latest records for each ledger account based on variationID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns in Balance table.

```
account   variation_id   amount     
  101        1            20
  101        1            10
  101        2            10
  101        2            50       
  110        4            13             
  110        3            20 
  110        4            40
  110        3            14   
  100        5            34    
  100        6            45
```

The result must be like this,

```
account   variation_id   amount     
  101        2            10
  101        2            50       
  110        4            13             
  110        3            40  
  100        5            34    
  100        6            45
```

I tried with below code to get max variation id and data but it didn't work.
I found all related questions to this but nothing has worked.

```
select amount, account,VARIATION ID from balance a,
         (select max(VARIATION ID) as ID,account from balance 
          where account=account 
          group by account ) b
where a.account = b.account
```

Please guide me how to get latest records with this data.

Comment: You should have a timestamp to know the latest records.Later get the latest two records with rank functions.

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT amount,account,VARIATION ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS RANK
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RANK < 3

Comment: Please clarify how you are getting that result table. It's not clear

Comment: What happened to variation 1?

Comment: How are you getting 110  3   40 ?

Comment: Why is 100  5   34 returned?

Answer (score 0):

Your o/p is not still clear to me but according to your query it should be *correlated* like that :

```
select b.*
from balance b
where variation_id = (select max(variation_id) 
                      from balance b1 
                      where b1.account = b.account
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE TBalance(
    Account INT,
    Variation_id INT,
    Amount INT
    );

INSERT INTO TBalance VALUES
(101, 1, 20),
(101, 1, 10),
(101, 2, 10),
(101, 2, 50),       
(110, 4, 13),             
(110, 3, 20), 
(110, 4, 40),
(110, 3, 14),   
(100, 5, 34),    
(100, 6, 45);

SELECT *
FROM TBalance TB1
WHERE TB1.Variation_id IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(Variation_id) AS Variation_id
        FROM TBalance TB2
        WHERE TB1.Amount >= TB2.Amount
        GROUP BY TB2.Account
    );
```

Results:

```
+---------+--------------+--------+
| Account | Variation_id | Amount |
+---------+--------------+--------+
|     101 |            2 |     10 |
|     101 |            2 |     50 |
|     110 |            4 |     13 |
|     110 |            4 |     40 |
|     100 |            5 |     34 |
|     100 |            6 |     45 |
+---------+--------------+--------+
```

As a note, there is no `Variation_id` =3 has `Amount` = 40, please correct your question.

Comment: Hi Sami, I tried as per your code but it is taking a long time to execute the query.

Comment: @rajini It's not slow for me, and it brings to you the expected results you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select * 
from ( select * 
            , dense_rank() over (partition by account order BY variation_id desc) as rn
       from table 
     ) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: @same from table.

Comment: I was thinking mybe it's a `VIEW` ;)

Comment: Please add `BY` to the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Hi Sami, I tried your code (DENSE_RANK), it is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: `select * 
from ( select * 
            , dense_rank() over (partition by account order BY variation_id desc) as rn
       from table 
     ) t
where t.rn = 1' and account like '10%'`

Comment: @Sami, I have used code like this but Can you please tell me how to use two like operators in the above query.

Comment: @rajini Sorry, I'm not the owner of this answer :)

Comment: I am sorry. I think @paparazzo answered dense_rank.thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use two like operators in the query..please help me